# How does Ā convert to the two characters - Ä€ - when opened in a text file, in Chrome

Tags: javascript, text, character-encoding, blob, arraybuffer

I have a text file with the following content:

```
Ā
```

This file is saved in UTF-8 encoding format and is worth 2 bytes.

Now the problem I have is that when I open this file using Google Chrome it shows me two characters, as illustrated below:

```
Ä€
```

I couldn't just understand **where are these two characters coming from?**

When I retrieve the content of the text file, shown above, using `Blob()` in JavaScript and then convert it into an `ArrayBuffer` and then to a `Uint8Array`, the typed array has the following two elements: `[196, 128]`.

I can definitely understand where these two numbers are coming from, but not how the number 128 produces the € character.

Comment: For some reason, Chrome decided to decode your file as [Win-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)

Comment: @georg can you please elaborate further. I would surely appreciate.

Comment: Chrome opened your file and decides, based on its internal algorithm, that that file should be interpreted as Win-1252. Since this is a single-byte encoding (1 byte = 1 char), Chrome displays two chars, with codes 196 and 128, which are Ä and €, according to the chart above.

Comment: So chrome is not using UTF-8.. But then how will it encode special characters that are above the range of Win-1252?

Comment: Encodings and unicode are complex topics. This classical article should be a good starting point: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/

Comment: Well thanks @georg!!! By the way I've already read the article you linked to. Anyway - really appreciate your effort.

Comment: A text file or stream reader must decode the bytes using the same character encoding that the writer encoded the text with. Knowledge of which character encoding is used should be shared somehow.  Some programs will guess, heuristically or not. HTTP and HTML have have standards. JSON has standards. Arbitrary text files do not have known standards.